# oracle data base error ORA-00920 invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my code after check syntax this error appear

> ORA-00920 invalid relational operator

```
select id,  classification
from  Closerfprfx
where classification in ('xxx','RFX','aa') and region('e','sdfsdf','dfg')
```

What problem on this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a function called `region` that accepts three string arguments, this code does not make sense:

```
region('e','sdfsdf','dfg')
```

I assume that you are missing the `in`:

```
 region in ('e', 'sdfsdf', 'dfg')
```

Comment: Even if REGION were a valid function, wouldn't he need to also compare the returned value to something?  WHERE ... AND REGION('e','sdfsdf','dfg') = 'somevalue'

Comment: @EdStevens . . . I'm pretty sure a user defined function can return a boolean type in PL/SQL.

Comment: I'm far from an expert in this particular area, but on your comment I did check _Database PL/SQL Language Reference 12.2_, and under CREATE FUNCTION - RETURN DATATYPE - found this .... "Oracle SQL does not support invoking functions with BOOLEAN parameters or returns. Therefore, for SQL statements to invoke your user-defined functions, you must design them to return numbers (0 or 1) or character strings ('TRUE' or 'FALSE'). "  But perhaps I'm missing something.  wouldn't be the first time! :-)